# Spring boot mongodb connection time out error

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am learning mongodb and basically I have a simple spring boot application which connects to a mongo db to save information.

My application properties is as follows:

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=emailDb
spring.data.mongodb.username=admin-user123
spring.data.mongodb.password=admin-password123
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

So I have created a docker-compose file to link the db with my spring boot app:

```
version: '3.2'

volumes:
  mongodb_data:     #creates mount point on docker for mongodb
    driver: local

# config postgres, Keycloak & Mongodb
services:
  servicel-component:
    image: servicel-component
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - email
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: message
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 8080:8080       # port for postgres
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - rabbitmq
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin-user123
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin-password123
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
networks:
  test:
    external: true
```

When u execute docker-compose up the following exception is triggered:

```
2020-08-07 09:35:23.063 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster

2020-08-07 09:35:23.143 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017


com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589) ~[na:na]

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[na:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

... 3 common frames omitted
```

When I don't run servicel-component on docker, just run it as mvn spring-boot:run and run mongodb on docker it works fine.
Any idea what i am missing here please?

Comment: You don't have mongo running on that port already do you, outside of docker?

Comment: Thanks the the reply, i have only one mongo running which is on docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use localhost, this refer to the container itself. You need use host IP or use docker DNS if the containers are in the same network (not your case).

```
2020-08-07 09:35:23.143 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i get the host ip of the mongo docker container?

Comment: If they are in the same network, you can use the name of the container: mongodb:27017

Comment: An alternative is to pass your host IP in a environment variable to your container. https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-65-get-your-docker-hosts-ip-address-from-in-a-container

Comment: Thanks i have added a cantainer name in the docker-compose file for mongo and define it in application properties spring.data.mongodb.host and it works